# Нажатие кнопки в другом классе

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, есть у меня клас main, в нем есть нажатие кнопки

```
public void vid_schet_ope(View v) {
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, 
        "Неверный логин или пароль", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно выполнить нажатие из другого класса, или, например, у меня есть процедура. Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

А собственно когда в другом классе может понадобиться нажатие на кнопку?
Ведь Вам наверняка главное не кнопка, а действие которое в результате выполняется
(если конечно вы не выполняете автоматизированное тестирование пользовательского интерфейса).

В таком случае другие классы по идее не должны использовать View, 
а работать с Control, в котором есть все необходимые обработчики событий.
Ссылку на Control можно передавать всем желающим вызвать тот или иной обработчик.

Наименование функций: [java code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html).

Answer (score 0):

Так протащите в тот класс ссылку на этот да вызовите этот метод оттуда.

Comment: делаю вот так glav gl = new glav(); gl.vid_schet_ope(v); выдает ошибку

Comment: Какую ошибку? И что за дурная манера названий? Разберитесь с naming convention.